# systemtap script

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, tracking, linux-device-driver

I want to write a script in systemtap and trace memory system call 
I want to catch number of memory system calls and memory used by specific process in a fix duration time
I don't know how to write this script.

Comment: What kernel version are you using? You may not need to use systemtap and be able to use the built in perf tools.

Answer (score 0):

A good startpoint is [this](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/wiki/WSKmemCacheAlloc) script.

Comment: thanks a lot i see I saw it before but it don't solve my problem please help me more

Answer (score 0):

The syscalls that allocate memory are sbrk and mmap, so those are the ones to look for.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the example for system calls from system tap and then make it specific for the system call you are interested in and print out the args of the system call:

http://sourceware.org/systemtap/examples/process/syscalls_by_proc.stp